# Tomcat access logs separately for different applications deployed inside it

Tags: java, tomcat7

Tomcat writes access_logs for all the applications together. Is it possible to write access logs separately for each application deployed in Tomcat depending upon their deployed names.

Eg: Inside logs dir,
       App1-->app1_access_logs
       App2-->app2_access_logs

Note: Im not talking about applications logs. Im talking about each request coming to particular application in tomcat from a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

I am 2 days late for dead-revival feast, nontheless I dig up this thread from its lay-buried mortuary position (also related to [Conditionally filter Tomcat AccessLogValve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347764/conditionally-filter-tomcat-accesslogvalve) among others)

To any adventurer wandering down here amongst dead-living threads, here is my suggestion :

- use https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html (and in particular "RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L,E=myFlag:true]" following a condition on queried URL) to add "myFlag" envVar
- use https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes "conditionIf" and "conditionUnless" attributes to do the filtering based on the envVar you just positioned